# How to delay emission between elements in Reactor Scheduler?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Now the difference in the execution time of `serviceBar.externalMethod1(string)` and `serviceBar.externalMethod2(string)` is equal to the difference in the call delay of `method1`and `method2`. I need the difference in processing between `serviceBar.externalApiMethod1` and `serviceBar.externalApiMethod2` to be minimum 1 second

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceFoo {
    private final ServiceBar serviceBar;
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("external-api-calls");

    public Mono<String> method1(String string) {
        return serviceBar.externalMethod1(string)
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(1), scheduler)
                .flatMap(resp -> {
                    /*some logic*/
                    return Mono.just(resp);
                });
    }

    public Mono<String> method2(String string) {
        return serviceBar.externalMethod2(string)
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(1), scheduler)
                .flatMap(resp -> {
                    /*some logic*/
                    return Mono.just(resp);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to do that `delaySubscription` on the other side, when you actually use them

Comment: And you probably want to delay only one of them to have a pause in _between_